# How to overflow specific content inside an <td>?

Tags: css, overflow

I start with a td cell like this

```
<td>
<span>123</span>
<input style="display:none;">
</td>
```

I'm looking for a way to style this so that the orignal content is hidden, the input box is shown and overflowing instead of resizing the td, and keeping the td sized to just its original content.

State A, which I have now, looks like this

[123][45aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa6][7aaaaaa89]

I want state B to look like this

[*input text field*aaaaaaaaa6][7aaaaaa89]

Comment: First of all, this looks like no valid code at all... Do you want to hide the span with css? And show the input? And a visible overflow on the td?

Comment: You cannot have scroll to TD, you have to put your content span, textbox inside div and div inside TD. You can style this div to have scroll bars as needed.

Comment: it was pseudo code, which i suppose wasnt a good idea

Comment: Ah and do you want to use javascript? To make these changes when a user clicks on a link or button for example?

Comment: Yes, I'm using javascript and jquery, I just dont know css well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  What I did not realize is that an element with position:absolute cannot be assumed to be defaulting to a 0,0 position, so I need to set the Left to 0 explicitly

```
<td>
 <div style="position: relative;">
  <span style="visibility:hidden;">123</span>
  <input style="position: absolute; left:0; display:inline;">
 </div>
</td>
```

Comment: display:none totally removes the element from the flow, visibility:hidden hides the element but it still will occupy space in the document. By the way, your elements and style-values are not closed properly (use ";" in between style-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
<span>123</span>
<input style="display:none;">
</td>
```

Is the correction for your markup, but what exactly is the effect you want to achieve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: And the input field should be in a form, although that form might be there somewhere wrapped around the table.

Comment: Agreed, think we need some more detailed information from the OP.

Comment: I tried "display:inline" which stretched out the <td>, I want "display:dont change the box just go on top of stuff;"

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
<span>123</span>
<div id="hidden">
<input type="text" />
</div>
</td>
```

in style define :

```
#hidden{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 margin:.5em;
}
```

make script that shows the div on over (you will need to include jquery js ...)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr td').children().find('div').hover(function(){
       $(this).show();
     }
    )
  });
</script>
```